# How to create multiple relationships to one model in Django?

Tags: python, django-models, one-to-many

I am learning to use Django with Postgres and I came across one issue. I know that django uses ForeignKey for many to one relationships but I feel like I would need one to many field for my issue :D.

Let me explain:
In one app 'User' I would have something like this:

```py
class UserProfile (models.Model):
    userObject = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 320)
    name = models.TextField(max_length = 60)
    language = models.CharField(max_length = 59)
```

In another app 'Notes' I would have this:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    note_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    like = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through=LikedNotes)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

Now how would I add for example favorite note to the relationship? My idea would be something like this:

```
class UserProfile (models.Model):
    userObject = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 320)
    name = models.TextField(max_length = 60)
    language = models.CharField(max_length = 59)
    favorite_notes = models.OneToManyField(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Now I know this is not an option but what would be best alternative? My goal would be to then easily add new favorite note to the user and get all of these favorite notes. I would like to be referencing the model directly. In my Note model I have the user column to check for the user that has created the note. Should I add the favorite option the same way? It seems little sloppy.

One to many field in Django is not an option, so I wanted to ask how you guys would resolve this relationship, as I feel like my solution with adding favorite column to notes, is not really the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an extra `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    note_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        UserProfile, through=LikedNotes, related_name='liked_notes'
    )
    favoured_by = models.ManyToManyField(
        UserProfile, related_name='favorite_notes'
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Ok, should I also create a through table for this case or would it be an overkill? I heard that plain many to many should be generally avoided.

Comment: @JohnnyHavlis: where did you read that? Django will automatically create a through model (which will thus generate a table). Only in case you want to store extra information in the relation you need to make a through model).